# Override publishTo in publishConfiguration in custom configuration

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to define custom behavior of `publish` task in my configuration `Deploy`, by changing `publishTo` to production server resolver and leave default resolver for publish in `Default` config, so i'm doing the following:

```
def deploySettings = addArtifact(Artifact(projectName, "zip", "zip"), Dist.pack) ++ Seq(
  publishTo := Some((publishRepo in ThisBuild).value)
)
```

This settings for default `publish` behavior (publish project to dev repo) and i also have a task called `deploy` in scope `Deploy`, which calls `publish` with `publishTo` setting defined in `Deploy` configuration:

```
private val deployConfig: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = inConfig(Deploy) {
  ...
  publishTo in (Deploy, publishConfiguration) <<= destination { _ map { _.resolver } },
  publishConfiguration in (Deploy, publish) <<= (publishConfiguration in Deploy),
  publishTo in (Deploy, publish) <<= destination { _ map { _.resolver },
  ...
}
```

But this doesn't work and when i call `deploy` or `deploy:publish` it publishes to dev repo from `*:publishTo` settings and if i won't provide `*:publishTo` in `deploySettings` execution crashes with:

```
last project/*:publishConfiguration
java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository for publishing is not specified.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$getPublishTo$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1186)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$getPublishTo$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1186)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.getPublishTo(Defaults.scala:1186)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$57.apply(Defaults.scala:1020)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$57.apply(Defaults.scala:1020)
```

Maybe the problem that SBT tryies to init `publishConfiguration` with `publishTo` from default configs? What should i correct to provide different resolver for `publish` in default scope and another one for `deploy:publish`?